# Get Product Name using Scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is my code to get the product name "**RENU FRESH LENS SOLUTION 120 ML**" from the url..this lies in the p tag..I just need this name.

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.lenskart.com/renu-fresh-lens-solution-100-ml.html"

source = requests.get(url)
data = source.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

pn = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"prcdt-overview"})[0].text
print pn
```

Comment: Ok. Do you also have a question?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: get the product name "RENU FRESH LENS SOLUTION 120 ML" only and not all the content

Comment: pn = soup.find_all('p')[3].text .. it can be solved using this..but dont know it is the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.lenskart.com/renu-fresh-lens-solution-100-ml.html"

source = requests.get(url)
# data = source.content   pass the variable in the BeautifulSoup()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, "lxml")
```

**Find() Version:**

```
pn = soup.find('div', class_="prcdt-overview").p.text
```

1. You do not need to import `'lxml'`, BeautifulSoup will do it for you
2. If you just need the first tag of `find_all()`, you should try `find()`, it will return first tag in the `find_all()`
3. You can use `tag.tag.find()/find_all()` to get the tag step by step.
4. `tag.tag_name` is the short name for `tag.find('tag_name')`

**CSS Selector Version:**

```
soup.select_one(".prcdt-overview p").text
```

1. `select_one()` will return the first tag of `select()`, like `find()` and `find_all()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
pn = soup.select(".prcdt-overview h1[itemprop=name] p")[0].text
```

or

```
pn =soup.select(".prcdt-overview")[0].select("h1[itemprop=name]>p")[0].text
```

and there are other ways as well, try these

Hope this helps

Comment: Go through this documentation as well, its pretty simple https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1):

more verbose way:

```
pn = soup.find_all("div", {"title":"prcdt-overview"})[0]
divTitle = pn.find("div",{"class":"title"})
pText = divTitle.find("p").text
print pText
```